# Readthedocs / Sphinx not rendering bullet list from rst file

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I have a set of rst files that I am building in readthedocs with sphinx. The files have multiple bullet lists, but they are not being rendered correctly.

The text appears, but there are no bullet symbols or nesting / indentation.

To make sure it was not my files, I did a direct copy-paste from the sphinx_rtd_theme page (https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/blob/b07560bf97dad3a4266f6145bd4b662ac708ab00/docs/demo/lists_tables.rst)

This is what the rst is supposed to render as (with `::marker` for each list item in the html file)

[image]

This is what I am getting when I build the same rst using my local sphinx / rtd setup

[image]

Is there something I need to fix in my conf.py or other files?

Comment: Hello!  You might be able to narrow down your problem a bit if you create an out of the box sphinx-quickbuild project using the RTD theme and see if the problem still exists when you include some bulleted lists.

Comment: Please edit your question to include any errors with loading CSS or JS files. Often when loading local files, browsers will block static assets for security.

Answer (score 19):

We had the same issue (bullet points disappearing in lists) after refreshing the conda environment we use for releasing one of our packages.  The other solutions listed here (thus far) didn't work for me, but downgrading `docutils <0.17` did.

We are using `nbsphinx` (some of our docs illustrate operations with notebooks), and had recently some issues due to related package versions (`jinja2`, `sphinx`, `docutils`). Based on issues/comments (such as [this one](https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/issues/549) and [that one](https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/issues/310#issuecomment-817624683)), we used various older versions of these packages.

But as of this writing and thanks to the hard work of all the maintainers, we were able to remove all pins except for `docutils`. FWIW, for our current needs, the relevant subset of packages we use is:

```
docutils                  0.16                     py38_1  
jinja2                    3.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
nbsphinx                  0.8.6              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
sphinx                    4.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
sphinx_rtd_theme          0.4.3                      py_0
```

Comment: More info on this bug at https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/bugs/417/ (it's not actually a bug in docutils, but in the CSS somewhere)

Comment: Edit: that CSS bug is in `sphinx_rtd_theme` (https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/1115). At this point, upgrading sphinx_rtd_theme>=0.5.1 worked for us (As well as upgrading sphinx>=4.3.0, but not sure if that is required. See github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/pull/961)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when using Read-The-Docs as a theme along with Sphinx-AutoAPI. Based on the answer of "Pierre D" I downgraded the `docutils` using:

```
conda install docutils=0.16
```

The solution worked for me. Both, missing bullets and the elongated line spacings were resolved. I guess the problem is caused by a bug in the `docutils` package and hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: Per https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/bugs/417/ , it's not actually a bug in docutils, but a CSS bug in sphinx_rtd_theme. See @ranger_rick's answer for more.

Comment: pip install docutils==0.16
when using pip

Answer (score 6):

Other answers here point to docutils as the having the bug. But, [the bug is actually in sphinx-rtd-theme](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/1115). So, even though downgrading docutils seems to work, the solution that worked for us, that I think is better, is to
*upgrade* sphinx and sphinx-rtd-theme past the bugfix. For us, that looked like requiring `sphinx>=4.3.0` and `sphinx-rtd-theme>=0.5.1` (see our [PR](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/pull/961))

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a issue with `sphinx_rtd_theme` and new HTML5 tags in `docutils`. See https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/1115 for more info. As mentioned, current resolution is downgrade to `docutils=0.16`.

Comment: Or, at this point, upgrading `sphinx_rtd_theme>=0.5.1` worked for us (As well as upgrading `sphinx>=4.3.0`, but not sure if that is required. 
 See https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/pull/961)

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered that an RtD documentation set I maintain was experiencing this exact problem, where bullets would show on my local builds (accompanied by the `::marker` in the page source) but would be absent in RtD builds (no `::marker` in the page source).

I tried a couple of things that didn't work before finding this thread. [Nick Crews's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71069918/4376000) worked perfectly: I [added the `>=0.5.1` lower-bound constraint to the `requirements-rtd.txt` file](https://github.com/bskinn/sphobjinv/commit/4999a5682f8bfe187b784ca9c3c991761f679f18) that I've [configured RtD to use](https://github.com/bskinn/sphobjinv/blob/4999a5682f8bfe187b784ca9c3c991761f679f18/.readthedocs.yml#L17) (I already had a `Sphinx==5.3.0` pin, for reasons), and poof! I had my bullets back.

**UPDATE 31 Jan 2023:** Based on the comments in [this `sphinx_rtd_theme` GitHub issue](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/1115#issuecomment-1373921098), it's ***also*** important to be sure that the version of `docutils` that gets installed is not too *high*. The thread recommends a constraint of `docutils<0.17`, though in recent builds my bullets have rendered fine with `docutils==0.17.1`.

---

This got me curious as to why it was necessary for me to add this constraint, when I'd already had `sphinx-rtd-theme` declared in `requirements-rtd.txt`.

On taking a closer look at my RtD build logs, I discovered that RtD has its own default-requirements install step, prior to installing anything I specify in my config. In this default install step, it was installing `sphinx-rtd-theme<5.0`:

```bash
Collecting sphinx-rtd-theme<0.5
  Downloading sphinx_rtd_theme-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.4/6.4 MB 117.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
```

Thus, when `pip` hit the `sphinx-rtd-theme` line in `requirements-rtd.txt`, it just ignored it, because *a* version of it was already installed:

```
Successfully installed  attrs-22.1.0  importlib-metadata-5.0.0  sphinx-5.3.0
 sphinx-issues-3.0.1  sphinx-removed-in-0.2.1  sphinxcontrib-applehelp-1.0.2 
 sphinxcontrib-devhelp-1.0.2  sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp-2.0.0  sphinxcontrib-jsmath-1.0.1
 sphinxcontrib-programoutput-0.17  sphinxcontrib-qthelp-1.0.3  zipp-3.10.0
```

Adding the `>=0.5.1` constraint thus forces an upgrade/reinstall of `sphinx-rtd-theme` to the latest version, fixing the problem.

---

So... where did this `sphinx-rtd-theme<0.5` pin come from?

After digging into the RtD source for a while, I found out that there's a [toggle](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/blob/0afdbe427204d9da12e4ddc2ed3a520c21174569/readthedocs/doc_builder/python_environments.py#L209-L215) for, essentially, "are we using the latest Sphinx version or not?":

```py
# If defaulting to Sphinx 2+, we need to push the latest theme
# release as well. `<0.5.0` is not compatible with Sphinx 2+
self.project.get_feature_value(
    Feature.USE_SPHINX_LATEST,
    positive='sphinx-rtd-theme',
    negative='sphinx-rtd-theme<0.5',
),
```

So, okaaay... I *do* want to use a recent version of Sphinx... why am I apparently set up to *not* `USE_SPHINX_LATEST`?

Looks like it's a [compatibility decision](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/build-default-versions.html#external-dependencies) made at some point. Any RtD docset created before a certain date (20 Oct 2020, for a personal project like mine; or, 21 Jan 2021 for RtD for Business projects) is set as `not USE_SPHINX_LATEST`. I assume these dates were picked for some strategic reason, likely having to do with in-the-wild usage of Sphinx < 2.0 dropping below some threshold.

Anyways! If you see a `sphinx-rtd-theme<0.5` and/or `sphinx<2` constraint in your RtD build logs, that's why. And, again, follow [Nick Crews's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71069918/4376000) to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, when listing using `*`, in the `.rst` file like:

```
* first item
* second item
```

I found out that the problem, in my case, was that I was using the theme `sphinx_rtd_theme`, but I didn't add it in `extensions` in the `conf.py` file. So adding the following worked for me:

```py
extensions = [sphinx_rtd_theme,
# other extensions
]
```

Comment: As written this fails with `AttributeError: module 'sphinx_rtd_theme' has no attribute 'startswith'`; I think it's looking for a string. Adding instead `'sphinx_rtd_theme'` as a string has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new sphinx project solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem:

Creating new `sphinx-quickstart` didn't work.
Reducing `docutils` to `0.16` and adding `'sphinx_rtd_theme'` to the `extensions` list in `conf.py` worked:

```
extensions = ['sphinx_rtd_theme']
```